# Why isn't here order invariance between the two sets of operations?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, data-science

I'm handling a CSV file/pandas dataframe, where the first column contains the date.
I want to do some conversion here to datetime, some filtering, sorting and reindexing.

What I experience is that if I change the order of the sets of operations, I get different results (the result of the first configuration is bigger, than the other one). Probably the first one is the "good" one.

Can anyone tell me, which sub-operations cause the difference between the results?

Which of those is the "bad" and which is the "good" solution?

Is it possible secure order independence where the user can call those two methods in any order and still got the good results? (Is it possible to get the good results by implementing interchangeable sets of operations?)

```
jdf1 = x.copy(deep=True)
jdf2 = x.copy(deep=True)
interval = [DATE_START, DATE_END]
dateColName = "Date"
```

Configuration 1:

```
# Operation set 1: dropping duplicates, sorting and reindexing the table
jdf1.drop_duplicates(subset=dateColName, inplace=True)
jdf1.sort_values(dateColName, inplace=True)
jdf1.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

# Operatrion set 2: converting column type and filtering the rows in case of CSV's contents are covering a wider interval
jdf1[dateColName] = pd.to_datetime(jdf1[jdf1.columns[0]], format="%Y-%m-%d")
maskL = jdf1[dateColName] < interval[0]
maskR = jdf1[dateColName] > interval[1]
mask = maskL | maskR
jdf1.drop(jdf1[mask].index, inplace=True)
```

vs.

Configuration 2:

```
# Operatrion set 2: converting column type and filtering the rows in case of CSV's contents are covering a wider interval
jdf2[dateColName] = pd.to_datetime(jdf2[jdf2.columns[0]], format="%Y-%m-%d")
maskL = jdf2[dateColName] < interval[0]
maskR = jdf2[dateColName] > interval[1]
mask = maskL | maskR
jdf2.drop(jdf2[mask].index, inplace=True)

# Operation set 1: dropping duplicates, sorting and reindexing the table
jdf2.drop_duplicates(subset=dateColName, inplace=True)
jdf2.sort_values(dateColName, inplace=True)
jdf2.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

Results:

```
val1 = set(jdf1["Date"].values)
val2 = set(jdf2["Date"].values)

# bigger:
val1 - val2

# empty:
val2 - val1
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Could you provide some data? The output of `df.to_json()`, and preferably a sample small enough to recreate the problem.

Comment: I've experienced this problem on a bigger (preprocessed) dataset, it's not easy to recreate the problem in small scale or get the data from the environment.
I am using a dataset similar to this (please change the data format to this: '%d-%b-%y') http://finance.google.ca/finance/historical?q=AAN&startdate=01+01+2016&enddate=01+01+2017&output=csv

Answer (score 1):

In first look it is same, but NOT.

Because there are 2 different ways for filtering with affect each others:

```
drop_duplicates() -> remove M rows, together ALL rows - M
boolean indexing with mask -> remove N rows, together ALL - M - N
```

--

```
boolean indexing with mask -> remove K rows, together ALL rows - K
drop_duplicates() -> remove L rows, together ALL - K - L
```

```
K != M
L != N
```

And if swap this operations, result should be different, because both remove rows. And it is important order of calling them, because some rows remove only drop_duplicates, somerows only boolean indexing.

In my opinion both methods are right, it depends what need.

Comment: OP is looking at a list of values, dropping duplicates and keeping values that fall within an interval. Could you give an example where the order of operations affects the result?

Comment: I think your first line is incorrect here, should look like this:
drop_duplicates() -> remove M rows, together ALL rows - M

Comment: If I understand your example correctly, you mean:
size(K) ~!= size(M), size(L) ~!= size(N), size(K) ~!= size(L), size(M) ~!= size(N)
where '~!=' operator means: 'not necessarily equals'
But what I am expecting is this:
size(K+M) <= size(K) + size(M) and size(L+N) <= size(L) + size(N) (where overlapping records are considered) and size(K+M) == size(L+N)
Isn't that true?

Comment: But in the case the execution order of the two operator sets should be in irrelevant. Am I right?

Comment: Not sure if understand. But order of operation is from row 1 to last row of code, if not some for, while,  if statements.

Comment: I try create some data sample and failed simulate your behaviour. Still both operations return same output. So problem is something else, can you give me your real data (only column `Date`) with `interval = [DATE_START, DATE_END]` where is problem? My answer working if check duplicates in one column and filter by condition in another column. Or if format datetimes is changed after `to_datetime`. thanks.